# Charging a battery pack using a motor

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, automotive-engineering, motors, battery

I want to fit a Hub motor ($15kW$ BLDC motor) to my car to convert it into a hybrid vehicle.
Would it be possible for me to use the same motor (as a generator) to charge my battery pack, while the vehicle runs on it's normal Internal Combustion engine?

Comment: Yes it should work, unless there is controlling circuitry in the motor itself that prevents it.

Comment: Kelvin-Watts is not a meaningful unit for anything related to a BLDC.

Answer (score 1):

There is no theoretical reason for this not to work, but there are many practical considerations, such as the fact that BLDC's typically produce 3-phase power, which would require extra components to convert for use as a charging source, and there may be issues with back-driving any internal gearbox that may be present. E-bikes regularly include regenerative braking functionality, so you could look into this. Without more details on your exact setup, we can't be of any further help.